# Overflow: hidden makes layout jumpy during transition

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've been trying to make a CSS only animated search bar. It works well when you click on it, but when you tab to it, the elements inside the search box jump left and then back while it's expanding. Removing `overflow: hidden` from the .search_box seems to fix it, but I can't figure out why. What's causing the jumpiness?

I'm using chrome v 101.0.4951.41, on windows 10

```css
.search_box {
    outline: 0.1em solid black;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100vh;
    width: 1.5em;
    transition: width 350ms;
    overflow: hidden; /*this breaks it*/
}

.search_box input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.2em;
    left: 0.3em;
    width: 10em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 350ms;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search_box p {
    display: block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
    border-radius: 100vh;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.search_box:focus-within {
    width: 12em;
}

.search_box:focus-within input {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS only slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="search_box">
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Make a search" />
        <p>&#128269</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What browser/system are you on I do not experience jumpiness when I tab to the search bar (Edge/Windows 10).

Comment: Windows 10 Chrome. I should have specified that in the question. I still get jumpiness in edge, but not in firefox.  Maybe it's a browser specific bug?